# How to add order number to multivalue fields classes?

Tags: 7, theming

A node with a multivalue image field looks something like this in html (the part which displays images):

```
<figure class="clearfix field-item even"><a><img src=....></a></figure>
<figure class="clearfix field-item odd"><a><img src=....></a></figure>
....
<figure class="clearfix field-item even"><a><img src=....></a></figure>
<figure class="clearfix field-item odd"><a><img src=....></a></figure>
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
<figure class="clearfix field-item even image01"><a><img src=....></a></figure>
<figure class="clearfix field-item odd image02"><a><img src=....></a></figure>
....
```

One way is to write a node--contenttype.tpl.php and inside, instead of `print render($content);` make a big loop which will render the fields one by one, adding the necessary class with number to images.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at [template_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7)? You should be able to modify the class array.

Comment: Once you know the hook name, everything suddenly becomes easy.. This is exactly what I was looking for, please make it an answer!! I also found an article about this [here](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/adding-css-classes-fields-drupal), and implementing this hook in conjunction with mytheme_field() function gives full control over every aspect of the field.

Comment: Done. I'll make some more research about the `$hook` parameter when I have some time to spare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[template_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) gives you the ability to manipulate fields before they are printed. Just like with `template_preprocess_page()` and `template_preprocess_node()`. Not sure what the `$hook` parameter is for and I have never needed it myself.

Since this is a preprocess function that will be executed for each field, you should add a condition for your field name. Something like this will do:

```
function THEME_OR_MODULE_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'FIELD_NAME') {
    // Manipulate the data. use dsm() or print_r() to see the array structure.
  }
}
```

**Edit:** It would seem as if `$hook` is always passed as the string 'field', which would be quite useless. Can anyone confirm this?

**Edit 2:** Okey, so you actually don't need `template_preprocess_field()` at all if you can override theme_field.

Below is a working example of a extended [theme_field($variables)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/theme_field/7) function based of the original version. There is also a good tutorial/example [here](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/adding-css-classes-fields-drupal), which @camcam shared in a comment.:

```
function THEME_NAME_field($vars) {
  $output = '';
  $i = 0;

  // Render the label, if it's not hidden.
  if (!$vars['label_hidden']) {
    $output .= '<div class="field-label"' . $vars['title_attributes'] . '>' . $vars['label'] . ':&nbsp;</div>';
  }

  // Render the items.
  $output .= '<div class="field-items"' . $vars['content_attributes'] . '>';
  foreach ($vars['items'] as $delta => $item) {
    $classes = 'field-item ' . ($delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even');

    // Add Row index to classes and iteriate row index variable.
    if ($vars['element']['#field_name'] == 'FIELD_NAME') {
      $classes .= ' row-' . $i;
      $i++;
    }

    $output .= '<div class="' . $classes . '"' . $vars['item_attributes'][$delta] . '>' . drupal_render($item) . '</div>';    
  }
  $output .= '</div>';

  // Render the top-level DIV.
  $output = '<div class="' . $vars['classes'] . '"' . $vars['attributes'] . '>' . $output . '</div>';

  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! A propos Edit 2, I came to the same conclusion, after some experimenting with code. But I used 2 functions: MYTHEME_field to declare the themed field names and then function theme_MYFIELDNAME that returns the html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to do this.

```
$('figure.field-item').each(function(index) {
   $(this).addClass("image" + index);
});
```

Comment: This won't work if you have to fields with markup that matches `figure.field-item`. The index will continue to iteriate when it's done with the first field.